# How to get raw encoded vorbis-data with libvorbis?

Tags: vorbis

I need to encode a PCM sample (captured from audio input) with vorbis codec. An [example](https://github.com/xiph/vorbis/blob/master/examples/encoder_example.c) I found shows how to encode WAV to ogg, and the `vorbis_block` structure (which holds the raw encoded buffer as it seems) has no public members according to [documentation](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/libvorbis/reference.html). I don't need ogg. I need to mix this raw encoded audio data with a VP8 video packet in a WebM container (realtime audio/video recording).

**How to get raw encoded audio buffer with libvorbis?**

Comment: Do the same but with the encoder you want? does libvorbis support this audio stream type?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, I already implemented webm container class and can stream and record WebM videos... but without sound. That is what I want to add - audio. WebM can store vorbis or opus audio data with vp8/9 video track